# Where is oid in pg_tblspc error message

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Recently I got `could not read block` error by displaying the following message:

```
pg_tblspc/16010/PG_9.3_201306121/16301/689225.365
```

After this error, I am trying the below query by assuming few of the numbers as `oid`, but my query result is empty rows.

```
select oid,relname from pg_class where oid=16010 or oid=16301;
```

Now my question is, what are the numbers on that `pg_tablspc`? I have gone through the [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/storage-file-layout.html) and I believe I might have missed the main point from there too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: *much* more detailed write-up at http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-filename-to-table/

The following info doesn't consider relfilenode changes due to vacuum full etc.

---

In:

```
pg_tblspc/16010/PG_9.3_201306121/16301/689225.365
```

we have:

- `pg_tblspc`: Indicates that it's a relation in a tablespace other than the default or global tablespaces
- `16010`: the tablespace oid from `pg_tablespace.oid`,
- `PG_9.3_201306121`: A version-specific, catversion-specific string to allow different Pg versions to co-exist in a tablespace,
- `16301`: the database oid from `pg_database.oid`
- `689225`: the relation oid from `pg_class.oid`
- `365`: The segment number. PostgreSQL splits big tables up into extents (segments) of 1GB each.

There may also be a fork number, but there isn't one in this path.

---

It took a fair bit of source code digging for me to be sure about this. The macro you want is `relpathbackend` in `src/include/common/relpath.h`, for anyone else looking, and it calls `GetRelationPath` in `src/common/relpath.c`.

Comment: Never thought about digging the source code. Thanks for your help and a comprehensive answer. It will do for me.

Comment: I think we should probably document it, since it's visible in errors the user might see. OTOH, it shouldn't happen unless something's broken.